# Running function in IOLoop.current().run_in_executor?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I read the following code

```
async def f():
    sc_client = session.client("ec2")
    for id in ids:
        await IOLoop.current().run_in_executor(None, lambda: client.terminate(id))
```

How does it compare to the following code? Will `client.terminate` be run in parallel? But each execution is awaited?

```
    for id in ids:
        client.terminate(id)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will client.terminate be run in parallel?

NO, it still runs as sequence.

`IOLoop.current().run_in_executor` will run the `blocking function` in a separate thread and returns an `asyncio.Future`, while `await` will wait until the `Future` which call `client.terminate` finish, then the loop continue.

**The difference the 2 options you given is:**

If the program has other coroutine to run, using the 1st option, the other coroutine won't block, while using the 2nd option, the other coroutine will block to wait your for loop finish.

An example to make you understand it (Here, will use `loop.run_in_executor` to simulate the `IOLoop.current().run_in_executor` for simple sake):

**test.py:**

```
import asyncio
import concurrent.futures
import time

def client_terminate(id):
    print(f"start terminate {id}")
    time.sleep(5)
    print(f"end terminate {id}")

async def f():
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()

    for id in range(2):
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as pool:
            await loop.run_in_executor(pool, client_terminate, id)
        # client_terminate(id)

async def f2():
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    print("other task")

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(*[f(), f2()])

asyncio.run(main())
```

**The run output is:**

```
$ python3 test.py
start terminate 0
other task
end terminate 0
start terminate 1
end terminate 1
```

You could see the `two client_terminate` in for loop still runs in sequence, **BUT**, the function `f2` which print `other task` inject between them, it won't block `asyncio scheduler` to schedule `f2`.

**Additional:**

If you comment the 2 lines related to `await loop.run_in_executor` & `threadpool`, directly call `client_terminate(id)`, the output will be:

```
$ python3 test.py
start terminate 0
end terminate 0
start terminate 1
end terminate 1
other task
```

Means if you don't wraps the `blocking function` in a `Future`, the `other task` will have to wait your `for loop` to finish which waste CPU.

Comment: If the two functions `f()` and `f2()` is called in some contexts like `await asyncio.gather(*[f(), f2()])`, there will be no benefit of non-blocking for `f2()`, right?

Comment: No, `awaitable asyncio.gather(*aws, return_exceptions=False)` will `Run awaitable objects in the aws sequence concurrently`, see [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#running-tasks-concurrently). Instead, `await f() await f2()` will run one by one.